# Why are my Altair Data Visualizations not showing up in Github?

Tags: github, data-visualization, altair

https://github.com/rcokeley/data_visualization/blob/main/README.ipynb

I am really new to using Github. I created a Readme file and downloaded it as a .ipynb extension. The visuals are not showing up in Github.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Github's notebook viewer does not execute any embedded Javascript code, presumably for security reasons. Altair charts are rendered via javascript, so they do not appear in Github notebook views.

One way to address this is to embed a static PNG version of the chart in the notebook; this cannot be done without a notebook frontend extension. PNG embedding is done automatically if you render charts using Jupyter's frontend extensions: use `alt.renderers.enable('jupyterlab')` if using JupyterLab, or `alt.renderers.enable('notebook')` if using Jupyter Notebook. Note that both these approaches require correctly-configured Jupyter frontend extensions to be installed; see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html for details.